# Reserve Balance Increase for Each Trustline?

Tags: wallets, trustline

Is there an additional reserve balance required for "each trustline created",above the standard to create an account, or has this been eliminated?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, trustlines, offers, data entries and signers require base_reserve (currently 0.5 XLM) for each record

https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/fees.html#minimum-account-balance

Comment: For both token issuer and regular accounts? If an issuer has a million trustees does it need to have half a million XLMs in balance?

Comment: no, that's only for the account making the trustline